# How do I get the start time of processes arranged from the latest process

Tags: powershell

Which cmdlet do I run in PowerShell that not only gives start time of process but also the output is arranged either from latest or earliest

Answer (score 5):

```bsh
Get-Process | select * -first 1
```

Outputs all properties of the 1st process. Here you can see that there is a property called `StartTime`.

```bsh
Get-Process | select Name, StartTime
```

Outputs all the processes with their start time

```bsh
Get-Process | sort-object -property StartTime -descending | select Name, StartTime
```

Sorts the objects by property and only shows the name and start time.

Comment: It totally worked, just a few red comments but got the output I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet (or its alias `sort`) to sort the pipeline elements. For example, you can specify a property to sort by, and the sort order:

```
Get-Process | sort -Property StartTime -Descending
```

Use the [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet (or its alias `select`) to control what properties to display or customize the output:

```
Get-Process | select -Property Name, StartTime
```

Note that some processes might throw an "access denied" exception when accessing the `StartTime` Property, so make sure to **run as Administrator** or specify the [error action](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/erroraction-and-errorvariable/) to ignore those processes:

```
Get-Process | sort StartTime -Descending -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select Name, StartTime
```

Also, it seems the `Idle` process does not have a `StartTime` set, so you could filter the processes first using the [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet (or its alias `where`):

```
Get-Process | where Name -ne Idle
# or
Get-Processs | where {$_.Name -ne "Idle"}
# or
Get-Process | where {$_.StartTime}
```